# How can I solve for $y$ in this multivariable calculus problem? (Critical points)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I have the function $$f(x,y) = x^2 \cdot e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}$$

Gradient is:

$$ f_x :(2x-x^3) \cdot e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} $$

$$ f_y : -x^2y \cdot e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}$$

In order to find critical points $f_x$ and $f_y$ need to be zero:

I can solve $f_x$ by investigating $$ ( 2x-x^3) = 0 \implies x_1 = 0, x_{2,3} = +-\sqrt{(2)}$$

When I use x = 0, y can be any value. But when x is $\sqrt{(2)}$ how can I solve for y? I always end up with a term $ e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} = 0$ which has no solution. (The solution gives the critical points as $(-\sqrt{(2)},0) ; (\sqrt{(2)},0)$

Comment: your $f_y$ should not have the negative sign in front.

Comment: I made a mistake the minus sign is before the brackets in the original function..

Comment: I am not to sure your $f_x$ is entirely correct.

Comment: @Owen I recalculated it and to the best of my knowledge it should be correct. The solution also gives this solution. It product rule and chain rule and then factor out (2x-x³)

Comment: right, my bad, I was thinking derivative w/ respect to $x$ instead of partial...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x=0$, then $(0,y)$ is a critical point for esch $y$.

If $ x \ne 0,$ then $x = \pm \sqrt{2}$. From $f_y=0$  we get $y=0$. This gives the critical points $(\pm \sqrt{2},0).$